# How to implement Waveform animation in android?

Tags: android, audio

I am Developing an Audio player in android, i want show a waveform or any other playing animation like this

[image]

Can any one please tell me how to achieve this , what is the best approach for this

Comment: Does it need to be dynamic? (like actually go with the music) if not then you can use [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html)

Comment: ya it should be dynamic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an Android class called Visualizer; it allows you to access audio being played: [Official Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html)

Please refer to [this link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/wallpapers/MusicVisualization/) to find some example you can download; you can start from one of that, modifying what you need.

Please find [here](https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer) another example to donwload.